# HC and HAC in SARIMAX

Tags: statsmodels

I can use HC and HAC without issues in the OLS framework in statsmodels. Can somebody tell me how to use it in SARIMAX framework?

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
res_ols = sm.OLS(y, X).fit(cov_type='HC3')
              Coef.    Std.Err.      z      P>|z|     [0.025   0.975]
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept    -0.0001     0.0014   -0.0756   0.9398   -0.0028   0.0026
oney          0.7919     0.0166   47.7080   0.0000    0.7594   0.8245

from statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax import SARIMAX
res_sarimax = SARIMAX(y,X, order=(0,0,0)).fit()
                 coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept     -0.0001      0.001     -0.079      0.937      -0.003       0.003
oney           0.7919      0.003    232.920      0.000       0.785       0.799
sigma2         0.0048   8.07e-05     58.906      0.000       0.005       0.005
```

You can see in the outputs above that the coefficients are the same but the std err are much more constrained in OLS with heteroskedasticity correction applied. How can I impose these correction in SARIMAX version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SARIMAX` has the option `cov_type='robust'`, which provides an set of standard errors that may be valid even in the presence of some misspecifications.

Note that these are slightly different in their details than the `OLS` robust standard error options, because `SARIMAX` estimated parameters via numerical maximum likelihood techniques.

Comment: Thanks @cfulton. This library you contributed is brilliant! As an aside, do you have run time comparisons of this python code versus pure C implementations?

Comment: Thanks for this nice comment! Unfortunately we don't have a set of benchmarks that we keep updated, although note that the code underlying `SARIMAX` is written in Cython, and so it is compiled to C already in our implementation.